# How to avoid re-link in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I wrote a simple makefile, and not able to avoid unnecessary re-linking

```
Target: foo1.o foo2.o
    LINK COMMAND

.c.o:
    COMPILE command
```

Each time I try to **make TARGET**, even if no source files have been updated, the **LINK** command is always run.

How can I avoid this unnecessary re-link ?

Thanks,

Comment: As written, that should work (except for the case changes).  Can you provide the actual makefile and a transcript of running it twice?

Comment: Abstracting complicated code is a good plan, but one does have to be careful to insure that the abstract version actually represents the full code.

Comment: Thanks @wnoise and @dmckee, I figured out the problem. I tried to save the executable in another directory i.e., **tmp/foo**, makefile does not detect the timestamp of the sub-directory. By changing the **TARGET** as **tmp/TARGET** solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a comment: See [Empty InfoWindow when Marker is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689311/empty-infowindow-when-marker-is-clicked) )

The OP wrote:

> I tried to save the executable in another directory i.e., tmp/foo, makefile does not detect the timestamp of the sub-directory. By changing the TARGET as tmp/TARGET solves the problem.