# Empty InfoWindow when Marker is clicked

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

This is my code to add new Markers to my GoogleMap:

```
MarkerOptions m = new MarkerOptions();
m.title(title);
m.snippet(snippet);
m.position(location);
mMap.addMarker(m);

mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(DemoActivity.this, "WindowClicked: "+ marker.getTitle() + ":" + marker.getSnippet(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Now This works just fine when my `title` and `snippet` are in English. The `infoWindow` and the `Toast` works as expected.

However, as in my case, `title` and `snippet` are in Arabic, the `Toast` works fine but ***the InfoWindow shows empty window***.

It seems to me like a bug related to Arabic language. Is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way around this would be to show a custom info window. You can do this by creating a [InfoWindowAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html) and setting it with [GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setInfoWindowAdapter).

> To replace the default info window, override getInfoWindow(Marker) with your custom rendering and return null for getInfoContents(Marker). To replace only the info window contents inside the default info window frame (the callout bubble), return null in getInfoWindow(Marker) and override getInfoContents(Marker) instead.

More Info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows

Comment: @iturki This didn't solve my problem. I still have empty window when using Arabic. What did you do exactly to solve the issue ?>

Comment: I want to center align the info window text, as in my app, marker pin text is multi lingual... and for arabic its getting align left, and some text is hiding in the info Window...

Answer (score 8):

@jimmithy answer solved my question.

This is just *a three-step implementation* of it from [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Popups):

**Step 1**: Create the layout of your infoWindow. Here is `popup.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="2dip"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:contentDescription="@string/icon"/>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/snippet"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="15sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 2:** Create your implementation of InfoWindowAdapter. Here is `PopupAdapter` class:

```
class PopupAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {
  LayoutInflater inflater=null;

  PopupAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
    this.inflater=inflater;
  }

  @Override
  public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    return(null);
  }

  @Override
  public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    View popup=inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

    TextView tv=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.title);

    tv.setText(marker.getTitle());
    tv=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
    tv.setText(marker.getSnippet());

    return(popup);
  }
}
```

**Step 3:** In your Activity, set your adapter to the GoogleMap:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
```

And you are set!

Comment: Error inflating Class, @ this line 
View popup=inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

Further,
02-06 14:40:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(24275): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020078 a=-1 r=0x7f020078}

Answer (score 3):

you should use this command `.title("\u200e"+"عربی").`