# How to extract an nth word from a variable and assign it to another variable in a makefile

Tags: makefile

My makefile has:

```
 debug:
    W1 := foo bar cat
```

I want to extract each word foo, bar and cat and get the output as below:

```
v1=foo

v2=bar

v3=cat
```

I tried:

```
W1 :=foo bar cat

v1 :=$(word 1, $$(W1))

v2 :=$(word 2, $$(W1))

v3 :=$(word 3, $$(W1))

debug:

     @echo "${v1}"
     @echo "${v2}"
     @echo "${v3}"
```

Does not work the way I wanted. Please help

Comment: Why are you using double-dollar signs?  That simply tells make to not expand the value, so you definitely won't get what you want.  Use `$(word 2,$(W1))` etc.

Comment: Also since the variables are make (and not shell) variables you can use `echo '${v1}'` (or `echo '$(v1)'` which would be my preference) in the rule body instead of using double quotes.

Comment: @MadScientist, Thanks, single dollar works.
Thanks for the suggestion Etan.

Answer (score 1):

(Answered in a comment. See [Empty InfoWindow when Marker is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689311/empty-infowindow-when-marker-is-clicked) )

@MadScientist wrote:

> Why are you using double-dollar signs? That simply tells make to not expand the value, so you definitely won't get what you want. Use `$(word 2,$(W1))` etc.

@Etan Reisner wrote:

> Also since the variables are make (and not shell) variables you can use `echo '${v1}'` (or `echo '$(v1)'` which would be my preference) in the rule body instead of using double quotes.