# How to run the targets parallely in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile :

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(EXECUTABLE)


$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
%.o: %.cpp
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(<F) -o $@
```

When we execute this, we can see that the targets main.o, hello.o, factorial.o are running in serial, as these are independent of each, can we make them to run in parallel.

```
g++ -c -Wall main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -c -Wall hello.cpp -o hello.o
g++ -c -Wall factorial.cpp -o factorial.o
```

If yes, please help me

Comment: You use the word "run" a lot.  Do you mean "compile"?  If so, please edit your question.

Comment: Call `make -j $number`, where `$number` is the maximum number of processes you want it to spawn in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a comment. See: [Empty InfoWindow when Marker is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689311/empty-infowindow-when-marker-is-clicked) )

@Wintermute wrote:

> Call `make -j $number`, where `$number` is the maximum number of processes you want it to spawn in parallel.

See also the documentation here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html#Parallel